# Ignore nan when finding min/max value across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with 5 date fields. Rows may have a value for all 5 fields or as few as 1.

How do I find the minimum or maximum value by row, ignoring nan values?

Example dataframe:

```
In [1]:
AccountID    CreatdDate    ContactDate     GiftDate     Sign-up Date
1            5/7/2017      nan             1/1/2018     5/7/2017
2            2/6/2020      2/6/2020        2/6/2020     2/6/2020
3            8/29/2010     4/22/2022       4/22/2022    8/4/2022
4            11/25/2017    nan             nan          nan
5            4/2/2014      1/6/2012        4/2/2014     nan
```

Desired new column:

```
Out [1]:
AccountID    Date
1            5/7/2017
2            2/6/2020
3            8/29/2010
4            11/25/2017
5            1/6/2012
```

I could write a function that takes into account all possible combinations of non-nan values, but that seems very inefficient for both me and the script.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas by default remove missing values if count converted columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `min/max` per rows:

```
cols = ['CreatdDate', 'ContactDate', 'GiftDate', 'Sign-up Date']
df1 = (df.set_index('AccountID')[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime).min(axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='Date'))
print (df)
   AccountID       Date
0          1 2017-05-07
1          2 2020-02-06
2          3 2010-08-29
3          4 2017-11-25
4          5 2012-01-06
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('AccountID')[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        .min(axis=1)
        .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        .reset_index(name='Date'))
print (df1)
   AccountID        Date
0          1  05/07/2017
1          2  02/06/2020
2          3  08/29/2010
3          4  11/25/2017
4          5  01/06/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert all the dates to datetime type and be able to get the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) per row unambiguously, then convert back to string with the desired format:

```
non_date_cols = ['AccountID']
df2 = df.drop(columns=non_date_cols).apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=False)

out = (df.drop(columns=df2.columns)
         .assign(Date=df2.max(axis=1).dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y'))
       )
```

Output:

```
   AccountID        Date
0          1    1/1/2018
1          2    2/6/2020
2          3    8/4/2022
3          4  11/25/2017
4          5    4/2/2014
```

For both min/max, change the last part to:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=df2.columns)
         .assign(Date_min=df2.min(axis=1).dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y'),
                 Date_max=df2.max(axis=1).dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
                )
       )
```

Or:

```
out = df[non_date_cols].join(df2.agg(['min', 'max'], axis=1)
                                .apply(lambda s: s.dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y'))
                                .add_prefix('Date_')
                             )
```

Output:

```
   AccountID    Date_min    Date_max
0          1    5/7/2017    1/1/2018
1          2    2/6/2020    2/6/2020
2          3   8/29/2010    8/4/2022
3          4  11/25/2017  11/25/2017
4          5    1/6/2012    4/2/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple tested solution solution,
mainly, make sure you have dates, and use skipna while comparing dates :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create example dataframe
data = {'AccountID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'CreatdDate': ['5/7/2017', '2/6/2020', '8/29/2010', '11/25/2017', '4/2/2014'],
        'ContactDate': [np.nan, '2/6/2020', '4/22/2022', np.nan, '1/6/2012'],
        'GiftDate': ['1/1/2018', '2/6/2020', '4/22/2022', np.nan, '4/2/2014'],
        'Sign-up Date': ['5/7/2017', '2/6/2020', '8/4/2022', np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date columns to datetime objects
date_cols = ['CreatdDate', 'ContactDate', 'GiftDate', 'Sign-up Date']
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# Find minimum and maximum values across all date columns
df['Date'] = df[date_cols].min(axis=1, skipna=True)

# Display result
print(df[['AccountID', 'Date']])
```

The output will should be like below :

```
   AccountID       Date
0          1 2017-05-07
1          2 2020-02-06
2          3 2010-08-29
3          4 2017-11-25
4          5 2012-01-06
```